# Print Circle Shape Outline in 1:1 ratio in Go

Tags: go, printing, shapes

I want to print a circle outline in Go, I have tried and it is works. But its shape is not in 1:1 ratio when it is printed in terminal. How can I correct it?

And Also I need to calculate character space inside the circle. (I need to know what is the radius to fill this amount of characters inside the circle)

I have tried this with ellipse. But I couldn't find an equation to find the character area inside the circle. `a := 7.96, b := 6.72, c := 2.04 - float64(area)` for quadric equation. But this is not 100% accurate. Highly appreciate if someone help. me through this.

Below is the code what i have tried

[You can view my code here](https://play.golang.org/p/RE0uxuY1pHw)

My current out put is like this

```
        *****        
      ***   ***      
    **         **    
   **           **   
  **             **  
  *               *  
 *                 * 
 *                 * 
**                 **
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
**                 **
 *                 * 
 *                 * 
  *               *  
  **             **  
   **           **   
    **         **    
      ***   ***      
        *****
```

My expected output is like below

```
                *********                 
            ***           ***             
        **                     **         
      **                         **       
    **                             **     
   **                               **     
  *                                   *   
 **                                   **   
*                                       * 
*                                       * 
*                                       * 
*                                       * 
*                                       * 
 **                                   **   
  *                                   *   
   **                               **     
    **                             **     
      **                          **       
        **                      **         
            ***           ***             
                *********
```

Answer (score 1):

Your circle is deformed because characters are not as wide as they are toll. I solved this by using elipse instead of circle.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func inDistance(x, y int, len, tolerance float64) bool {
    return math.Abs(len-math.Hypot(float64(x)/2.3, float64(y))) < tolerance
}

func main() {
    plane := make([][]byte, 100)
    for i := range plane {
        plane[i] = make([]byte, 200)
    }

    for y, r := range plane {
        for x := range r {
            if inDistance(x-50, y-50, 20, .5) {
                plane[y][x] = '*'
            } else {
                plane[y][x] = ' '
            }
        }
    }

    for _, v := range plane {
        fmt.Println(string(v))
    }
}
```

[[image: the result1]